# How many aurors guarded Hogwarts in Harry Potter's 6th year?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, ministry-of-magic

In *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*, it was mentioned that the Ministry for Magic offered protection to Hogwarts by placing more counter-curses, anti-intruder jinxes and a small task force on the grounds of Hogwarts Castle for the sole purpose of protecting the school. So, how many Aurors did Rufus Scrimgeour place in Hogwarts grounds to protect the castle?

Answer (score 3):

## Tonks mentions herself and 3 others.

During Harry and Tonks' dialogue in HPB she mentions other Aurors guarding Hogwarts.

> "But what are you doing here, anyway?" Harry asked
>
>  "I'm stationed in Hogsmeade now, to give the school extra protection," said Tonks.
>
> "Is it just you who's stationed up here, or -?"
>
> "No, Proudfoot, Savage, and Dawlish are here too."
>
> "Dawlish, that Auror Dumbledore attacked last year?"
>
> "Thats right."
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half Blood prince, Chapter 8 (Snape Victorious)*</sup></sub>

Comment: But there are more than 30 Death Eaters, so how come 3 to 4 aurors are sufficient in protecting Hogwarts?

Comment: as you mentioned there was also protective charms/jinxes and members of the staff would be willing to fight.

Comment: @Ken_To_2018 plus, it's the same with normal police, you don't expect a full scale attack on a single target. If someone is "under protection", they have a few cops stationed close-by, even if they are "under protection" from the let's say the mafia (typically alongside being placed somewhere unknown if there is a serious threat).  The small group is enough to help detect an attack early and sound the alarm bells to get the whole auror squad there if indeed it would be a frontal assault in force. That's why Malfoy goes for the cabinet, to stage a quick assault from inside.

Answer (score 2):

In the harry potter and the half blood prince game there are 5 or 6 Aurora on the marauders map guarding each area of Hogwarts, I can't find the particular map I want but if you play that game it will show you but this wikia shows you the locations which they guard, it may or may not be canonical to the movie though.

http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Half-Blood_Prince_(video_game)